# Google script trigger to run only on Monday/Wednesday/Friday

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm running a **SendEmail** script with a 3 triggers to be sent out on Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

I have 10 sheets on the spreadsheet (each one contains an **SentEmail** script and each needs to be sent out on those days but I have only 20 trigger limitation)

This is the code:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('BCX');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var range = s.getRange('B5:Q20');
  var row = ss.getSheetByName('BCX').getRange("J1").getValue();
  var to = "info@google.com";
  var body = '';
  var htmlTable = SheetConverter2.convertRange2html(range);
var body = "Hi Team!"
     + htmlTable
     + "<br/><br/><b><i>**This is an automated email**</i></b><br/><br/>Any question please let me know.<br/><br/>Regards,<br/><br/>";
  var subject = "Google | Report " + row;

  MailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {htmlBody: body});
};
```

But if I use something like the following script it will create 3 triggers each week until it reaches 20 triggers (trigger limit).

```
function createTriggers() {
   var days = [ScriptApp.WeekDay.MONDAY, 
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.WEDNESDAY,                                            
               ScriptApp.WeekDay.FRIDAY];
   for (var i=0; i<days.length; i++) {
      ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmail")
               .timeBased().onWeekDay(days[i])
               .atHour(7).create();
   }
};
```

Comment: I cannot understand the logic of ``But if I use something like the following script it will create 3 triggers each week until it reaches 20 triggers (trigger limit).``. When your ``createTriggers()`` is run, 3 triggers are created for running ``sendEmail`` every Monday, Wednesday and Friday as "Week timer". I think that when ``createTriggers()`` was run once, such trigger can be created. If I misunderstand your question, please tell me.

Comment: I need the first script to run on Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays for 10 sheets, that means 10 SendEmail scripts + 1 trigger for each day for each SendEmail script which trigger limitations doesnt allow more than 20

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. I couldn't understand about what you want to do. You use 10 sheets in one Spreadsheet? Or you use 10 Spreadsheets? It seems that your script uses one sheet in one Spreadsheet. So can you update your question by including the detail information of the logic? Because in your question, By this, I think that it will help users understand your issue and think of your solution.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike I have edited the question and yes, I have 10 sheets on the spreadsheet (each one contains an SentEmail script and each needs to be sent out on those days but I have only 20 trigger limitation)

Comment: Thank you for updating it. When you use 10 sheets in one Spreadsheet, I think that you can run a trigger by scanning each sheet. So I cannot understand the logic of ``each one contains an SentEmail script and each needs to be sent out on those days but I have only 20 trigger limitation``. Can you explain about the detail of it? If my understanding of your situation is not correct, please tell me.

Comment: I have 10 sheets in 1 spreadsheet.
Each sheet contains a report
Each report needs to be sent out on Monday, Wednesday and Friday.
The script **SentEmail** contains the information that I need to send of each sheet (one script per sheet).

I just don't know how to add within the Sent Email the logic to run only on Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, although I cannot see the vision of your situation, for example, I think when one script uses all sheet, it might achieve it by 3 triggers. Or when the script delete and create the trigger every time, it might achieve it by 1 trigger. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: As you stated... 1 script per sheet with 3 triggers... But I cannot have more than 20 triggers.

Comment: I think that if I could see the clear vision of your situation, it was possible to discuss concretely. But unfortunately, I couldn't see it from your question and comments. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52489270/google-script-trigger-quota-limitation)

Comment: @JuanPabloMarroquinOcampo **tehhowch** suggested that you modify your script so that just one trigger is needed. Have you tried that? Your `sendEmail` function is limited to just one sheet on one spreadsheet. Why not keep the same function but change it so that it loops though each sheet on the spreadsheet, and does `sendEmail` for each sheet. That's one function but it covers 10 sheets; so if you set it to run three times a week, that's only three triggers.

Comment: I got it now @Tedinoz but my coding skills are not that advanced, thats why I coudn't join the scripts, besides I cant loop the same function to all the sheets as each sheet sends emails to a different distro (I think that is my dilema).

Comment: If all the spreadsheets are in the same folder(s), or if you have a list of the spreadsheets, then looping through the sheets is not that hard. Regarding the distro, wouldn't that be recorded in each spreadsheet - how else would you know?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this question would be to combine the various scripts into a single script that can be triggered to run on Monday, Wednesday and Friday.

Within the script, the sequence of processing would be:
1) loop through the spreadsheets in a given folder/sub-folders of Google Drive. - this provides the unique spreadsheet ID.
2) for each spreadsheet, get the ID and use the `openById(ID)` to open the spreadsheet.
3) get the sheets for the spreadsheet
4) for each sheet, use the original code to build and send an email.
5) rinse and repeat for the next sheet, and next spreadsheet.

The following **untested** code combines the search for every spreadsheet within a specific folder and sub-folders, opening the spreadsheet and getting the sheets, and then looping through each sheet. The questioner need only add the name of the Google Drive Folder to initiated the search, and put their own code in the two places indicated.

```
function 53383834() {
    /* Adapted from Code written by @hubgit https://gist.github.com/hubgit/3755293
    Updated since DocsList is deprecated  https://ctrlq.org/code/19854-list-files-in-google-drive-folder
    */


    // List all files and sub-folders in a single folder on Google Drive
    // declare the folder name
    var foldername = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'; // enter the folder name

    // declare this sheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActivesheet();

    // getFoldersByName = Gets a collection of all folders in the user's Drive that have the given name.
    // folders is a "Folder Iterator" but there is only one unique folder name called, so it has only one value (next)
    var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(foldername);
    var foldersnext = folders.next();

    // list files in this folder
    var myfiles = foldersnext.getFiles();

    // spreadsheets have a unique MIME-Type = application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet
    var searchTerm = 'spreadsheet';

    // loop through files in this folder
    while (myfiles.hasNext()) {
        var myfile = myfiles.next();
        var fname = myfile.getName();
        var fid = myfile.getId();

        // get the MIME-Type and test whether the file is a spreadsheet
        var ftype = myfile.getMimeType();
        var indexOfFirst = ftype.indexOf(searchTerm);
        if (indexOfFirst != -1) {
            var ssid = fid;
            // open the spreadsheet
            var sso = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
            // get the sheets
            var sheets = sso.getSheets();
            var sheetlen = sheets.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < sheetlen; i++) {
                // get the sheets, one by one
                var thissheet = sso.getSheets()[i];

                <<
                insert questioners code here >>

            }

        }

    }


    // Now get the subfolder
    // subfolders is a Folder Iterator
    var subfolders = foldersnext.getFolders();


    // now start a loop on the SubFolder list
    while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
        var subfolderdata = [];
        var mysubfolders = subfolders.next();
        var mysubfolder = mysubfolders.getName();

        // Get the files
        var mysubfiles = mysubfolders.getFiles();

        // now start a loop on the files in the subfolder
        while (mysubfiles.hasNext()) {

            var smyfile = mysubfiles.next();
            var sfname = smyfile.getName();
            var sfid = smyfile.getId();
            var sftype = smyfile.getMimeType();
            var indexOffolder = sftype.indexOf(searchTerm);
            if (indexOffolder != -1) {
                var ssid = sfid;
                // open the spreadsheet
                var sso = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);
                // get the sheets
                var sheets = sso.getSheets();
                var sheetlen = sheets.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < sheetlen; i++) {
                    // get the sheets, one by one
                    var thissheet = sso.getSheets()[i];

                    <<
                    insert questioners code here >>

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```